# How can I scrape all existing text on a page with scrapy?

Tags: python, text, web-scraping

I have this code that extracts a bunch of stuff from urls and follows some links but I would like to get all existing text on the websites. In response.css(), is there an attribute that lets you choose every existing tag?

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
import lxml.html
import pandas as pd
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor



class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "dialpad"

def start_requests(self):

    #pass in your URLs here
    urls = [
        'https://www.dialpad.com/',
        'https://www.domo.com/'
    ]
    allowed_domains = [i for i in urls]
    for url in urls:
        BASE_URL = url
        rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'{}/.*'.format(url), ))), )
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):

    #enter your path to where you want to save results
    root_path  = "~/Desktop/DataSci/results_scrape"

    page = response.url.split(".")[1]
    filename = 'quotes-thing-{}.csv'.format(page)
    BASE_URL = response.url

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:

      for h in response.css('body').xpath('.//text()'):
        selector = h.extract()
        f.write(selector)

      for href in response.css("li > a::attr('href')"):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse)
        for thing in response.css('body').xpath('.//text()'):
            thing = thing.extract()
            f.write(thing)
```

Answer (score 4):

This code gives you all type of tags in data.

```
data = """
... <html><head>
...
"""
tag_list = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for tag in soup.find_all():
     print (tag.name)
     tag_list.append(tag.name)
```

You should use following code on your project , if you want to extract specific tags like 'href'
;

```
desired_elements = []
linkerHref_list = response.css('body').xpath("//*[@href]")

for link in linkerHref_list :
     test = link.get_attribute("href")
     desired_elements.append(test)
```

Comment: your first code snippet may be what i need. to get "data" from the site you need to extract the html itself correct? what's the command for that?

Comment: 'data' is a response of your desired url's doctype html. For example:: data = requests.get('https://www.google.com').text      ;   after that ;
print(data)   
>>>'<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype=.......